# Most efficient way to compile unique values in a massive text file?

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have a set of large text files that in total contain about 3 million rows.

What I want to do is pluck a value from a given column from each row and add it to an array in memory. If the value already exists in the array, then ignore it.

I'm assuming the fastest way is NOT:

- Read a value
- if exists (using array's native index or what-have-you method), then push it to the array

Should I be inserting the value in alphabetical order to speed up the match/search?

OR should I keep multiple arrays...for example, one for each letter of the alphabet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html):

> Set implements a collection of unordered values with no duplicates. This is a hybrid of Array's intuitive inter-operation facilities and Hash's fast lookup.

Example usage:

```
require 'set'

set = Set.new
set << 1 << 2 << 3  # => #<Set: {1, 2, 3}>
set << 2            # => #<Set: {1, 2, 3}>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add the values as keys to a hash map, that would take care of removing duplicates automatically. You could even count the number of times each value occurs this way (with the hash value).

Comment: Assuming you don't have a proper set data structure at hand. (I don't know Ruby very well, maybe there's really nothing like that within reach. I'm just saying this approach simulates a set using a hash table.)

Comment: @delnan Indeed Ruby does have a Set data structure, see my answer `:)`.

Comment: Yep, a Hash is possible. Does that get significantly slower as the number of keys greatly increases? Counting instances is useful but not necessary, so efficiency is the focus.

Comment: You're right, you could of course use a set as well. Then it becomes a bit harder to count occurences though.

Comment: @Zando, you should only see a significant slowdown if the required memory becomes really large and the machine starts swapping or something like that.